# Spark for Neo4j does not load all relationships into the DB

Tags: apache-spark, neo4j

Hello fellow big data explorers.

I'm using Spark to load in ~11 million relationships into the graph.(Yes, all nodes are in the graph)

this is how I'm using Spark to load in the relationship data.

```
dfRelationships.repartition(2).write.format("org.neo4j.spark.DataSource")\
.option("url", "neo4j://someurl:7687") \
.option("authentication.type", "basic")\
.option("authentication.basic.username", f"{username}")\
.option("authentication.basic.password", f"{password}")\
.mode("overwrite")\
.option("relationship", "CONNECTED")\
.option("transaction.retries", 100)\
.option("batch.size",1000)\
.option("relationship.save.strategy", "keys")\
.option("relationship.source.node.keys", "parent:id")\
.option("relationship.target.node.keys", "child:id")\
.option("relationship.source.labels", "node")\
.option("relationship.target.labels", "node")\
.save()
```

Not using .repartition(2) leads to some race condition issues.

dfRelationships has been filtered and every entry has been cleaned.

```
parent , child
1        2
2        3
2        4
```

once the Write command has been successful I only see about 4.5 million relationships in the graph.
The thing that gets me is that this command has been running completely fine a few days ago and I saw all the edges get loaded.

Does neo4j cache the relationships even though I ran the below command from the neo4j browser?

```
:auto
MATCH (n:Node)
CALL { WITH n
DETACH DELETE n
} IN TRANSACTIONS OF 50000 ROWS;
```

I'm just lost as to why it is so inconsistent. It was working a day ago loading in all relationships.
Wondering if there is something on the DB side that needs to be configured.
Just out of ideas on what might cause this. debug and query logs also do not show anything. Would appreciate any feedback.

EDIT/Solution:

"Since I have dual label vertices I didn't set the 'node' label on all of my vertices this caused neo4j to be unable to find those vertices because the index is only set on the 'node' label.
I missed out on setting a label on some vertices which caused them to not be indexed."

Why do we need dual labels?

Our use case calls for dynamic label queries which Cypher at this point in time does not support. Meaning that Cypher is only able to do queries such as

`MATCH (u:User {username:'admin'}),  (r:Role {name:'ROLE_WEB_USER'}) CREATE (u)-[:HAS_ROLE]->(r)`

If you notice the User label and Role label are basically hardcoded and there is no way to have them dynamically change based on the data.(big issue when you have a network graph where random labels will be paired with other random labels. we would need to find every type of relationship possible and then write a custom query for each type, by labeling everything as 'node' our relationship table simply becomes one instead of splitting our data) I believe there should be some apoc library that might be able to do that but I've yet to find it.

Let's say you have a relationship table such as

```
parentid , childid, parentLabel, childLabel
1           2         User        Role
2           3         Admin       Role
2           4         Actor       Played
```

If you notice above for each relationship row you would need to process them separately because Cypher isn't able to change the labels dynamically.

`MATCH (u:User {username:'admin'}),  (r:Role {name:'ROLE_WEB_USER'}) CREATE (u)-[:HAS_ROLE]->(r)`

`MATCH (u:Admin {username:'admin'}),  (r:Role {name:'ROLE_WEB_USER'}) CREATE (u)-[:HAS_ROLE]->(r)`

`MATCH (u:Actor {username:'admin'}),  (r:Played {name:'ROLE_WEB_USER'}) CREATE (u)-[:HAS_ROLE]->(r)`

VS if the data was like this

```
parentid , childid, parentLabel, childLabel
1           2         NODE        NODE
2           3         NODE        NODE
2           4         NODE        NODE
```

Everything can be loaded in as such

`MATCH (u:NODE {username:'admin'}),  (r:NODE {name:'ROLE_WEB_USER'}) CREATE (u)-[:RELATIOSNSHIP]->(r)`

Comment: Since `overwrite` mode will not create duplicate relationships, does `dfRelationships` contain duplicate rows and/or specify relationships that already exist in the DB (if you are loading into an existing DB)?

Comment: Nope I did dropDuplicates() on it. I also delete all the relationships before a load. Append will not work in the long term.

Comment: "I believe there should be some apoc library that might be able to do that but I've yet to find it." <-- It does, I use ```apoc.merge.node``` & ```apoc.merge.relationship``` to dynamically create label based on input data

Answer (score 1):

I encountered a similar issue a few days ago. When working with a large number of relationships, it's considered a best practice to create an index on your nodes. This allows the Neo4j-Spark-Connector algorithm to efficiently insert relationships. You can add the index to the options list when you're adding your nodes, like this:

```
.option("schema.optimization.type", "INDEX")
```

If you don't know how an index works, [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_index) could be useful.

Comment: Yep Index is necessary but it was an error on my side. I missed out on setting a label on some vertices which caused them to not be indexed.